# When $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{I}$, why are the columns of $\mathbf{X}$ uncorrelated with each other?

Tags: probability

Suppose $\mathbf{X}$ is an $n \times p$ matrix consisting of $p$ column vectors. I have read that when $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{I}$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix, the columns of $\mathbf{X}$ are uncorrelated with one another. The intuition I can see is that the columns of $\mathbf{X}$ are perpendicular to each other.

However, I am unable to formally prove this. I believe I want to show that

$$
Corr\left(X_i,X_j\right) = \dfrac{Cov(X_i,X_j)}{SD(X_i)SD(X_j)} = 0 \qquad \text{for all} \ i \neq j
$$

But I cannot see how $Cov(X_i,X_j) = E(X_iX_j) - E(X_i)E(X_j) = 0$, since a sufficient condition for $E(X_iX_j) = E(X_i)E(X_j)$ is independence, which is not implied by uncorrelatedness. Am I missing something simple here? Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify how you define the mean in this context? The most obvious definition admits an $n=p=2$ counterexample from rotation matrices.

Comment: Your question, as stated, makes little sense. The concept of correlation applies only to random variables. Is $X$ a random variable here? If yes,  then $X^t X$ is also a random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false: $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1 \\1&-2\end{bmatrix}$$ has columns that are perpendicular but not uncorrelated.

It becomes true if you additionally assume that every column sums to zero. In that case, the covariance simplifies to $E(X_i X_j)$ which is just $\frac1n$ times the dot product.

---

You may be thinking of this in the context of a multivariate normal distribution. In that case, we have $z \in \mathbb R^n$ whose every component is chosen from the standard normal distribution, and $(X_1 \cdot z, X_2 \cdot z, \dots, X_p \cdot z)$ are a general centered multivariate normal.

In this case, the random variables $X_1 \cdot z, \dots, X_p \cdot z$ are indeed uncorrelated exactly when $X_1, \dots, X_p$ are orthogonal. That's because $E(X_i \cdot z) = 0$ and $E((X_i \cdot z)(X_j \cdot z))$ simplifies (after some expansion) to $X_i \cdot X_j$.